# Can I calculate median if I do not have individual data points?

Tags: excel

I need to calculate Median Time per Activity & Average Time per Activity.
I have only total data (Total number of activities & Total time). Average I calculated simply by dividing the two. Can I calculate Median from total data or do I need individual data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need all data points, if you want to get the median of a sorted list of numbers